# ASP.NET Web API: what's its target?

Tags: .net, rest, soa, asp.net-web-api, saas

I've been playing with ASP.NET Web API samples (http://www.asp.net/web-api/samples).

After some hours of reading articles, checking source code and so on, I got a question.

What's the target of ASP.NET Web API?

- RESTful APIs for Web sites that look to expose some subset of their system to third-parties.

... or/and??? ...

- Pure RESTful APIs that aren't necessarily for Web sites, but for creating SOA or SaaS solutions <--- **This is why I'm evaluating different APIs**.

In addition, *how would it perform ASP.NET Web API working with high-demand services?*

Thank you in advance for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the short description and this should have made it super clear by now:

> ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP
>   services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and
>   mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building
>   RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.

It is all about HTTP. REST is not in your face. But if you wanna make your application 100% pure REST, ASP.NET Web API is your choice in .NET.

As for the scale-out scenarios, ASP.NET Web API is asynchronous from top to bottom (including extensibility points) and the framework infrastructure allows you to scale out insanely. Of course, it doesn't prevent you to shoot yourself in the foot. You can still write garbage with ASP.NET Web API if you are not careful enough.

Comment: @tugberk Right, but your answer just confirms what I can found in the official web page. And when I say *how would it perform [...]*, think that a convention over configuration heavily relies on **reflection**, and that's Web API: less configuration, more convention. In the long run, in a high-demand platform, such thing could have performance impact. In the other hand, I dislike your part of *REST isn't in your face*.... In fact, I'm asking this question because there're other approaches using pure WCF others than WebAPI and I'm comparing everything to take the right decision.

Comment: I've successfully implemented REST or HTTP APIs using pure WCF without any starter kit, just using Streams, ASP.NET compatibility mode and custom classes for handling requests/responses RESTFuly. Now that Web API is here, why don't take a look at it? But it's not about "I want REST because it's trending" or because I don't know that *it's all about HTTP*. **I just want to get more accurate info, and I'm not looking for default statements for selling products! You know** :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer if you have a working system and u are happy with it, then that's absolutely fine to me. IN ASP.NET Web API, the programming model is so much different than WCF and maybe that's gonna make you more happy. There is a nice introduction video which will make you get started: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV309 I am sure after playing with it for couple of days, you will see the difference.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer as for the reflection part, you will see that lots of lookups are cached internally and it won't hurt your performance. One other benefit to chose Web API over WCF is that ASP.NET Web API is open source: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com.

Comment: @tugberk Answer to "if you have working [...]". Not that happy haha, it's just some things were done in some way because there was no other solution out-of-the-box. WCF is harder to understand and sometimes extension points aren't that good. **Since I found Web API interesting, I asked such question, because it seems more friendly than WCF and it's for HTTP purely as you said, but I don't rely on a solution because it has an heroic name like ASP.NET Web API, but because I've checked its features, I've compared them with existing approaches and I got the necessary info to say "ok, go!"**

Comment: @tugberk Answet to "as for reflection part". +1 for that. I was guessing that Web API did some kind of routing cache, and if this is how it's built in its core, then, convention over configuration implementation is ok. Thank you for clarifying that because is a very important point.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer there are a lot more things which will make u happy. I have been playing with ASP.NET Web API since it was in its preview stage (WCF Web API) and I can see that the team has created an ineradicable, highly scaleable and extensible framework. Seriously, go and clone the repository and check the source code by yourself. You will be happy to do that.